# Disregarding the average if data contains a zero in python

Tags: python, numpy, average, zero

I am trying to create a function to calculate the moving average on a set of data. This is the function:

```
def averaged_rel_track(navg, rel_values, nb, zeroindex):
    #function to average the relative track values for each blade. This is 
    #dependant on the number values specified by the user to average over in a 
    #rolling average
    for blade in range(0,int(nb)):
        av_values=[]
        rel_blade=rel_values[:,blade]
        for rev in range(0,len(rel_blade)):          
            section=rel_blade[rev-int(navg)+1:rev]
            av_value=np.mean(section)
            av_values.append(av_value)

        print av_values
```

however I would like to add a check to it and  I'm strugging witht the best way to implement this...
If the number of averages (`navg`) in the moving average is say 24 the average is taken of the 23 values before the specified element and the element. However, if one of those 24 values is a zero I want the average for that specified element to be zero. I tried:

```
def averaged_rel_track(navg, rel_values, nb, zeroindex):
    #function to average the relative track values for each blade. This is 
    #dependant on the number values specified by the user to average over in a 
    #rolling average
    for blade in range(0,int(nb)):
        av_values=[]
        rel_blade=rel_values[:,blade]
        for rev in range(0,len(rel_blade)):          
            section=rel_blade[rev-int(navg)+1:rev]
            av_value=np.mean(section)
            zero_test= np.where(np.any(section==0))
            print zero_test
            if len(zero_test)==0:
                av_value=None
            av_values.append(av_value)
        print av_values
```

However the length of zero_test is always 1?

Can anyone think of a way to correct this method or a different method altogether?

Cheers

Comment: I know this is a bit confusing, but more than happy to give more explination

Comment: See examples of efficient moving average calculations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352047/finding-moving-average-from-data-points-in-python

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do though. But you should try replacing all of the lines involving `zero_test` with `if np.any(section == 0):`

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mr E's comment I solved this by replacing `zero_test` with simply `np.any(section==0)`. This is a much simpler way of doing it.