# How to make this matplotlib plot less noisy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, smoothing

How can I plot the following noisy data with a smooth, continuous line without considering each individual value? I would like to only show the behavior in a nicer way, without caring about noisy and extreme values. This is the code I am using:

```
import numpy
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import spline

dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(fname='data', delimiter=",") 

dic = {}

for d in dataset:
    dic[d[0]] = d[1] 

plt.plot(range(len(dic)), dic.values(),linestyle='-', linewidth=2)

plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642478/249341), I was introduced to the [Savitzky Golay filter](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/SavitzkyGolay), a particular type of low-pass filter, well adapted for data smoothing. How "smooth" you want your resulting curve to be is a matter of preference, and this can be adjusted by both the window-size and the order of the interpolating polynomial. Using the cookbook example for `sg_filter`:

```
import numpy as np
import sg_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Generate some sample data similar to your post
X = np.arange(1,1000,1)
Y = np.log(X**3) + 10*np.random.random(X.shape)

Y2 = sg_filter.savitzky_golay(Y, 101, 3)

plt.plot(X,Y,linestyle='-', linewidth=2,alpha=.5)
plt.plot(X,Y2,color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it!

Here I show how to reduce noise using a variety of techniques:

1. Moving average
2. LOWESS regression
3. Low pass filter
4. Interpolation

---

Sticking with @Hooked example data for consistency:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(1, 1000, 1)
Y = np.log(X ** 3) + 10 * np.random.random(X.shape)

plt.plot(X, Y, alpha = .5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

1. Moving average

Sometimes all you need is a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

For example, using pandas with a window size of 100:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(Y, X)
df_mva = df.rolling(100).mean()  # moving average with a window size of 100

df_mva.plot(legend = False);
```

[image]

You will probably have to try several window sizes with your data. Note that the first 100 values of `df_mva` will be NaN but these can be removed with the `dropna` method.

Usage details for the [pandas rolling function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

---

2. LOWESS regression

I've used LOWESS (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing) successfully to remove noise from repeated measures datasets.  More information on local regression methods, including LOWESS and LOESS, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).  It's a simple method with only one parameter to tune which in my experience gives good results.

Here is how to apply the LOWESS technique using the [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.org/) implementation:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

y_lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(Y, X, frac = 0.3)  # 30 % lowess smoothing

plt.plot(y_lowess[:, 0], y_lowess[:, 1])  # some noise removed
plt.show()
```

[image]

It may be necessary to vary the `frac` parameter, which is the fraction of the data used when estimating each y value. Increase the `frac` value to increase the amount of smoothing. The `frac` value must be between 0 and 1.

Further details on [statsmodels lowess usage](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html).

---

3. Low pass filter

Scipy provides a set of [low pass filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) which may be appropriate.

After application of the lfiter:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter

n = 50             # larger n gives smoother curves
b = [1.0 / n] * n  # numerator coefficients
a = 1              # denominator coefficient
y_lf = lfilter(b, a, Y)

plt.plot(X, y_lf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Check [scipy lfilter documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) for implementation details regarding how numerator and denominator coefficients are used in the difference equations.

There are other filters in the [scipy.signal package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html).

---

4. Interpolation

Finally, here is an example of [radial basis function interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation):

```
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

rbf = Rbf(X, Y, function = 'multiquadric', smooth = 500)
y_rbf = rbf(X)

plt.plot(X, y_rbf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Smoother approximation can be achieved by increasing the `smooth` parameter. Alternative `function` parameters to consider include 'cubic' and 'thin_plate'. When considering the `function` value, I usually try 'thin_plate' first followed by 'cubic'; however both 'thin_plate'  and 'cubic' seemed to struggle with the noise in this dataset.

Check other `Rbf` options in the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf). Scipy provides other univariate and multivariate interpolation techniques (see this [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html)).