# Extract histogram modes by detecting the local maxima of a vector with NumPy/SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a way with NumPy/SciPy` to keep only the **histogram modes** when extracting the **local maxima** (shown as blue dots on the image below)?:
[image: Histogram]

These maxima were extracted using `scipy.signal.argrelmax`, but I only need to get the two **modes** values and ignore the rest of the maxima detected:

```
# calculate dB positive image
img_db = 10 * np.log10(img)
img_db_pos = img_db + abs(np.min(img_db))
data = img_db_pos.flatten() + 1

# data histogram
n, bins = np.histogram(data, 100, normed=True)

# trim data
x = np.linspace(np.min(data), np.max(data), num=100)

# find index of minimum between two modes
ind_max = argrelmax(n)
x_max = x[ind_max]
y_max = n[ind_max]

# plot
plt.hist(data, bins=100, normed=True, color='y')
plt.scatter(x_max, y_max, color='b')
plt.show()
```

**Note:**

I've managed to use this [Smoothing filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642478/2228912) to get a curve that matches the histogram (but I don't have the equation of the curve).

Comment: What do you mean by **discriminate** between maxima?

Comment: @kazemakase I meant to keep just the two modes and get rid of the other maxima detected. I should probably edit my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be achieved by appropriately adjusting parameter `order` of function [`argrelmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html#scipy.signal.argrelmax), i.e. by adjusting how many points on each side are considered to detect local maxima.

I've used this code to create mock data (you can play around with the values of the different variables to figure out their effect on the generated histogram):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema, argrelmax

m = 50
s = 10
samples = 50000
peak_start = 30
peak_width = 10
peak_gain = 4

np.random.seed(3)
data = np.random.normal(loc=m, scale=s, size=samples)
bell, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=np.arange(2*(m + 1) - .5), normed=True)
x = np.int_(.5*(edges[:-1] + edges[1:]))

bell[peak_start + np.arange(peak_width)] *= np.linspace(1, peak_gain, peak_width)

plt.bar(x, bell)
plt.show()
```

[image: mock data]

As shown below, it is important to carefully select the value of `order`. Indeed, if `order` is too small you are likely to detect noisy local maxima, whereas if `order` is too large you might fail to detect some of the modes.

```
In [185]: argrelmax(bell, order=1)
Out[185]: (array([ 3,  5,  7, 12, 14, 39, 47, 51, 86, 90], dtype=int64),)

In [186]: argrelmax(bell, order=2)
Out[186]: (array([14, 39, 47, 51, 90], dtype=int64),)

In [187]: argrelmax(bell, order=3)
Out[187]: (array([39, 47, 51], dtype=int64),)

In [188]: argrelmax(bell, order=4)
Out[188]: (array([39, 51], dtype=int64),)

In [189]: argrelmax(bell, order=5)
Out[189]: (array([39, 51], dtype=int64),)   

In [190]: argrelmax(bell, order=11)
Out[190]: (array([39, 51], dtype=int64),)

In [191]: argrelmax(bell, order=12)
Out[191]: (array([39], dtype=int64),)
```

These results are strongly dependent on the shape of the histogram (if you change just one of the parameters used to generate data the range of valid values for `order` may vary). To make mode detection more robust, I would recommend you to pass a smoothed histogram to `argrelmax` rather than the original histogram.

Comment: `order=4` did it for my histogram (shown above in the question).

Answer (score 8):

I guess, you want to find second largest number in `y_max`. Hope this example will help you:

```
np.random.seed(4)  # for reproducibility
data = np.zeros(0)
for i in xrange(10):
    data = np.hstack(( data, np.random.normal(i, 0.25, 100*i) ))

# data histogram
n, bins = np.histogram(data, 100, normed=True)

# trim data
x = np.linspace(np.min(data), np.max(data), num=100)

# find index of minimum between two modes
ind_max = argrelmax(n)
x_max = x[ind_max]
y_max = n[ind_max]

# find first and second max values in y_max
index_first_max = np.argmax(y_max)
maximum_y = y_max[index_first_max]
second_max_y = max(n for n in y_max if n!=maximum_y)
index_second_max = np.where(y_max == second_max_y)

# plot
plt.hist(data, bins=100, normed=True, color='y')
plt.scatter(x_max, y_max, color='b')
plt.scatter(x_max[index_first_max], y_max[index_first_max], color='r')
plt.scatter(x_max[index_second_max], y_max[index_second_max], color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]