# smooth the path of line with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of points, all together they create a track, where the sequence is crucial. I can plot the track using lines, how could I smooth it after or while new points are fetching? Track might look like 1 pic:

Picture One [image: Picture One]

Picture Two [image: Picture Two]

Picture Three [image: Picture Three]

2 picture is what I want to have in the end. I tried to interpolate with `scipy.interpolate` but it didn't work, because it requires sorted sequence (I only achieved pic3 in the end)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618804/how-to-smooth-a-curve-in-the-right-way

Comment: @quant as I see, this post uses interpolation of the line with direction from left to right, but my data (track) could be from left to right/right to left and others and have loops. So with interpolation it will be the same as pic2 from my post.

Comment: In this case, I would probably use Bézier curves - What do you think of something like this: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Jean-YvesQueinecBezierCurves.htm ?

Comment: yep, it close to the answer, but still smth not I want. Because the smoothed line will be far from the corners. In my case, the smoothed line should be close to straight lines and should round corners as close as possible to the corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a different interpolation method or approach might get what you want.  A cubic spline will get you straighter lines with curves at the vertices, as utilized from the scipy libary and this sample set of loop points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

arr = np.array([[0,0],[2,.5],[2.5, 1.25],[2.6,2.8],[1.3,1.1]])
x, y = zip(*arr)
#in this specific instance, append an endpoint to the starting point to create a closed shape
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]
#create spline function
f, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)
#create interpolated lists of points
xint, yint = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), f)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(xint, yint)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And original straight line would look like this:

[image]

Comment: how should we go to evaluate the spline fits in specific values (instead of 100 evenly spaced distance values)?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue to smooth a path, the [shapelysmooth package](https://pypi.org/project/shapelysmooth/) did the trick for me.

In my case, the best output was using [Chaikins-Algorithm](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Edm/UNC/COMP258/LECTURES/Chaikins-Algorithm.pdf) as I just wanted to remove some corners of the path. 
In the issue case (keep the corners), the Catmull-Rom Spline might be a better option.