# How can I give specific x values to `scipy.interpolate.splev`?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, bspline

How can I interpolate a [hysteresis loop](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&biw=2560&bih=1329&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=1Na-XOOWNMe_lwTG3aPgCw&q=hysteresis%20loop&oq=hysteresis%20loop&gs_l=img.3..35i39l2j0j0i67j0l4j0i67j0.42589.42902..43141...0.0..0.66.112.2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.GTcFIV470UA) at specific x points? Multiple related [questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points) are available on SOF regarding B-spline interpolation using `scipy.interpolate.splprep` (other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329268/7375944) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962986/7375944)). However, I have hundreds of hysteresis loops at very similar (but not exactly same) x positions and I would like to perform B-spline interpolation on all of them at specific x coordinates.

Taking a [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962986/7375944):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])

# append the starting x,y coordinates
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

# fit splines to x=f(u) and y=g(u), treating both as periodic. also note that s=0
# is needed in order to force the spline fit to pass through all the input points.
tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)

# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is it possible to provide specific x values to `interpolate.splev`? I get unexpected results:

```
x2, y2 = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(start=23, stop=25, num=30), tck)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(x2, y2, '-b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The b-spline gives x and y positions for a given u (between 0 and 1).
Getting y positions for a given x position involves solving for the inverse.  As there can be many `y`'s corresponding to one `x` (in the given example there are places with 4 `y`'s, for example at `x=24`).

A simple way to get a list of `(x,y)`'s for `x` between two limits, is to create a filter:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([23, 24, 24, 25, 25])
y = np.array([13, 12, 13, 12, 13])

# append the starting x,y coordinates
x = np.r_[x, x[0]]
y = np.r_[y, y[0]]

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x, y], s=0, per=True)

# evaluate the spline fits for 1000 evenly spaced distance values
xi, yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 1000), tck)

# plot the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y, 'or')
ax.plot(xi, yi, '-b')

filter = (xi >= 24) & (xi <= 25)
x2 = xi[filter]
y2 = yi[filter]
ax.scatter(x2, y2, color='c')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: If this answer solved your question you might consider marking it as accepted.