# any workaround to customize plotly multiple time series in python (updated)?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to customize plotly iplot that rendered multiple time series, but iplot accept only one parameters. I checked into plotly documentation, and usinf `go` object was mentioned. But I am still not able able to adding custom fonts and watermark to the plotly plot. Can anyone help me out? any possible idea to make this work?

**minimal data and demo code**

Here is the code that I tried to use for adding custom fonts and watermark on that. I am new to plotly so some fancy built int functions are not quite intuitive to me. Any possible help would be appreciated.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib as mpl
import cufflinks as cf
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:35% !important; } .widget-select > select {background-color: gainsboro;}</style>"))
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(1)
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi']= 440

# sample data from cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()

# plotly
iplot([{
    'x': df.index,
    'y': df[col],
    'name': col
}  for col in df.columns])
```

plus, I want to smooth the output of above code (which is multiple time series plot), how can I do that? any idea? Thanks

**update**

I have done this with `matplotlib` but don't know doing same thing in `plotly`. here is my script for loading customized font, watermark:

```
import matplotib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

fname=r'C:\Users\Nunito-Black.ttf'
myfont=fm.FontProperties(fname=fname,size=50)
legend_fname=r'C:\Users\RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf'
legend_font=fm.FontProperties(fname=legend_fname,size=20)
## some code for passing plot data to plotting function
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'mylogo',fontsize=60,fontproperties=myfont,color='black',
         transform=ax.transAxes,ha='center', va='center', alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

how can I do same things in plotly plot? any idea?

Comment: I can't see custom fonts or watermark in your code

Comment: @rpanai I have custom font and watermark file in my local drive. I could include that by using `import matplotlib.font_manager as fm`, but seems plotly won't me do that. any idea? thanks

Comment: @rpanai please see my updated script for loading and using custon fonts, water marks in `matplotlib`. any idea?

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? I don't have `RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf` so i can't reproduce

Comment: @rpanai I can share the file with you, can you open [this](https://jmp.sh/b/RyvLFeriXNRxaSKv572p) ? thanks

Comment: @rpanai any idea?

Comment: I'll have a look later on.

Comment: @rpanai I am looking at plotly documentation but didn't figure out smoothing above plot because what I tried gave me an error. Plus I want to use custom fonts and watermark on it. your possible guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @rpanai my question was simple, like how to smooth plotly line chart [how to smoothing plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618804/how-to-smooth-a-curve-in-the-right-way). is that doable in plotly as well? any idea?

Comment: I tried to use `KernelReg` without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This is not (yet) an answer.

I do not understand what do you mean by smooth on the first part. Anyway I see some not necessary imports plus it seems to me you use plotly with an old sintax.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd

df = cf.datagen.lines()

fig = go.Figure()
for col in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                   y=df[col],
                   name=col))

fig.show()
```

The output being 
[image]

Consider that in this case you could use `pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame()` instead of import `cufflinks`.

For the second part i suggest you to read the documentation for `go.Layout.font?` which is

```sh
   Supported dict properties:

        color

        family
            HTML font family - the typeface that will be
            applied by the web browser. The web browser
            will only be able to apply a font if it is
            available on the system which it operates.
            Provide multiple font families, separated by
            commas, to indicate the preference in which to
            apply fonts if they aren't available on the
            system. The plotly service (at https://plot.ly
            or on-premise) generates images on a server,
            where only a select number of fonts are
            installed and supported. These include "Arial",
            "Balto", "Courier New", "Droid Sans",, "Droid
            Serif", "Droid Sans Mono", "Gravitas One", "Old
            Standard TT", "Open Sans", "Overpass", "PT Sans
            Narrow", "Raleway", "Times New Roman".
        size
```

The usage in Python is [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/font-styling-in-python-using-custom-font/15125/2) and apparently the js version is more flexible see [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/what-are-all-the-different-types-of-font-styles-supported-by-plotly/1593/4)