# How to improve the Smoothness (steepness) of the curve using matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

In an experiment I conducted, I gathered the temperature data every 2 seconds. The experiment lasted over 3000s.

I tried plotting my findings with `matplotlib` with this sample code, after previously having imported each csv column into separate lists.

```
plt.plot(time, temperature)

plt.xlabel('Time' + r'$\left(s\right)$')
plt.ylabel('Temperature' + r'$\left(C\right)$')

# plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 3500, 500.0))
# plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 20, 2))

# plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.show()
```

My result is this:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0DEx.png)

How can I improve this:

- in order to make it smoother (maybe be experiment design - every 1 seconds data collection)
- in order to make it more scientific (adding legend and writing celsius symbol instead of C for temperature units)

Any other helpful suggestions are welcome.

**Edit: Sample Data**

```
Time,Temperature
0,19.77317518
2,19.77317518
4,19.77317518
6,19.77317518
8,19.77317518
10,19.77317518
12,19.77317518
14,19.77317518
16,19.77317518
18,19.77317518
...
40,19.36848822
42,19.36848822
44,20.379735
46,20.17760174
48,20.379735
```

Comment: It looks like the steps are artifacts of your data. Could it be that there are always two data points per time step, a higher and a lower one? Maybe post the first few elements of `time` and `temperature`?

Comment: In general, if you are trying to make the data smooth, the problem is called nonparametric regression. One possible, simple way is a smoothing spline, or LOESS. More sophisticated methods include wavelet smoothing and trend filtering. If you just want something quick-n-dirty, start with (centered) moving average or the smoothing spline.

Comment: @tilman151 Hey, thanks for taking a look. I've included the sample data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Celcius to `y` label:

```
plt.ylabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')
```

In order to `smooth` it, you should first use only markers

```
plt.plot(time, temperature, '.')
```

Matplotlib perform linear interpolation between 2 points this is why you have those "jumps"

If you want to fit a smooth line to the data check the following link:

[How to smooth a curve in the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618804/how-to-smooth-a-curve-in-the-right-way)