# Savitzky-Golay filter and plot the smoothed fit *with confidence intervals* in Python

Tags: python, smoothing, confidence-interval

i'm looking to implement a Savitzky-Golay filter and plot the smoothed fit *with confidence intervals*.

There's a scipy solution (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html and this [How to smooth a curve for a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618804/how-to-smooth-a-curve-for-a-dataset)), but it doesn't return confidence intervals.

Is anyone aware of a python implementation with confidence intervals?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.