# Python last three items in stream

Tags: python

I have a ultrasonic ping sensor getting output from it in Python. This reading is in a

```
while True:
```

so that obviously never stops.

That data is set to a var called 'ping_out'. I need to get the last three readings from ping_out and average them so that I get a var called ping_average. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that sets 'ping_out'? A queue of length 3 seems to be the appropriate data structure for this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352047/finding-moving-average-from-data-points-in-python

Comment: ping_out = timepassed * 17000. Timepassed is the time between sending the pulse and recovering it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a length 3 [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object:

```
from collections import deque
last3 = deque(maxlen=3)

while True:
    last3.append(this_ping)  # <-- insert your ping here, of course
    avg = sum(last3) / len(last3)
    print avg
```

Comment: Nice. Part of me wants to preoptimize that `len(last3)` bit because you only need to call it a maximum of three times.

Comment: i'd wonder how much your optimization would be negated by the overhead of said optimization :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the brilliant answer, and extremely quick reply!!!!! And thanks to you too @David for trying :) unfortunately, everyone on here has ridiculously quick typing ;)

Comment: @mhlester I can't imagine it'd be so bad :P https://gist.github.com/kojiromike/9258780

Comment: @kojiro, out of the frying pan and into the fire?